# Error - Function call not correct?

Tags: c++

Hello I am doing this project for my C++ class and I am having trouble with my code. I don't know if I should post the whole code as it is kind of long, however I am just going to post the function and where the error is at.

Here is the function-

```
void loadfile(int jeff[][4],int anna[][4])

{
 string fname;
 cout<< "Enter the name of the file to load:" << endl;
 cin>>fname;
 ifstream istream(fname);
 if(istream.is_open())
 {
      for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
      {
          if(i==0)
          {
               for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
               {
                    for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
                    {
                         istream>>jeff[j][k];
                    }
               }
          }
          else
          {
               for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
               {
                    for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
                    {
                         istream>>anna[j][k];
                    }
               }
          }
      }
      cout<<"New shcedule loaded successfully" << endl;
 }
 else
 {
      cout<<"Error in opening file" << endl;
      return;
 }
}
```

I get an error at

```
ifstream istream(fname);
```

The error says - error: no matching function for call to

Here is my call

```
case '6':
  loadfile(jeff, anna);
   break;
```

Comment: use `ifstream istream(fname.c_str());`.  Or use a modern compiler

Comment: 'istream' is defined type under the 'std' name space

Comment: @UchiaItachi it is legal to use `istream` as a variable name also,  although not a good idea

Comment: @M.M You're correct. I was taken back a bit pondering how is that using a class name as a variable name works. It's been long time i have encountered this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line you get the error at to

```
ifstream istream(fname.c_str());
```

It looks like your compiler is in C++98/03 mode.  In that case the `std::ifstream` constructor that opens a file takes a `const char*`.  The constructor that takes a `const std::string&` wasn't added until C++11.